# What is the next step with this user who continues to post biased off-topic comments?

Tags: discussion

I caught this question which was highlighted on the SE network:

[So, what is the advantage of using the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106039/so-what-is-the-advantage-of-using-the-terminal)

There's a user Mehrdad who has been posting comments attacking the CLI-oriented linux in favor of GUI-oriented Windows.  This question has nothing to do with Windows, yet he continues to make the comparison.

I have flagged his comments and most of them have been removed.  This morning, he has posted another one.  Apparently, simply removing the comments is not getting the message through to this user that these off-topic and highly-opinionated comments are unwelcome.

What is the next step?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have dropped a notice and will purge the comments from that answer later on.

The user has already been contacted and we will keep an eye on the situation.

Please feel free to contact any of the moderators any time with situations like this on meta or more directly try the general chat room.

Answer (score 7):

> What is the next step?

Exactly what you've done. We'll deal with it now.

* *Puts his boots on*